# How do I set the default umask in apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, fedora, file-permissions, upload

I need to set the default umask in apache on fedora so that my uploaded files have permissions 644 which are set to 600 by default in spite of doing chmod( $uploaded_file , 0644 ); in php script.
Can someone provide some direction...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Fedora, I believe it's in `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` and you change the umask there -- `umask xxx`.